# linking viewController functions through container view to table view controller

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv, uistoryboard

EDIT: This is a new question but I had to edit an old question to post it because I got a post limit.

I'm trying to link these 4 functions to the table view controller which is embedded in the container view. How do I do this?

The reason I'm using an embedded container is because I was getting errors with having a static table view controller, and I need a static table view controller so I can link both "labelSlider" and "labelSliderChanged" to the same view I have in the table view controller.

Here is a picture of the viewController.h and the storyboard files: http://postimg.org/image/o8moyzmar/

Comment: It is a too small and incomplete snippet: what is `pts`? And if `tempPoint` is a pointer (it's unclear), why `pts[ptsIndex] = &tempPoint`? You surely enable and act on *all* compiler warnings? But.. if you are using `..point..` to indicate your application rather than coding, it's poor nomenclature.

Comment: I posted an edit, hopefully that clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

Variables created on the stack will have their memory thrown back into the "free memory" pool once they are no longer in scope.

```
  CvPoint tempPoint; // this creates the CvPoint on the stack
  ...
  pts[ptsIndex] = &tempPoint; // here, you have assigned a local address
} // tempPoint's memory is released back to the system.
  // the pointer to this memory will now be pointing at garbage
```

Instead, why don't you just create `pts` as such:

```
CvPoint pts[POINT_TOTAL];
```

and then assign your values straight into it:

```
pts[ptsIndex] = tempPoint;
```

Comment: pts is being passed in as a parameter and is a pointer, so pts[ptsIndex] = tempPoint gives an error of "assigning CvPoint* from CvPoint"

Comment: You didn't do the first thing I said.

Comment: Please see my edit. I appreciate your help but I'm continuing to get errors. I'm now getting a breakpoint error when I call the DetectAndDraw function.